# TypeScript: How do I specify the type of a constructor wanting a constructor wanting a parameter?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have narrowed down my problem to the following minimal example:

```js
// interfaces:

interface ClassParameter{
    x:number
}

interface ClassParameterNeeder{
    y:number
}

type ClassParameterConstructor = new () => ClassParameter

type ClassParameterNeederConstructor =
    new (cpc: ClassParameterConstructor) => ClassParameterNeeder

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// implementations:

class MyClassParameter implements ClassParameter{
    x = 12
    extraField = 27
}

class MyClassParameterNeeder implements ClassParameterNeeder{
    y = 19
    otherExtraField = 29
    constructor(mcpc: new() => MyClassParameter) {}
}

let doesntWork:ClassParameterNeederConstructor = MyClassParameterNeeder
```

TypeScript complains about the last line:

```
let doesntWork: ClassParameterNeederConstructor
Type 'typeof MyClassParameterNeeder' is not assignable to type 'ClassParameterNeederConstructor'.
  Types of parameters 'mcpc' and 'cpc' are incompatible.
    Type 'ClassParameterConstructor' is not assignable to type 'new () => MyClassParameter'.
      Property 'extraField' is missing in type 'ClassParameter' but required in type 'MyClassParameter'.(2322)
input.ts(22, 5): 'extraField' is declared here.
```

This first made me wonder why the dependency seems reversed here, but it actually makes sense. In the declaration of type `ClassParameterNeederConstructor`, an outer Constructor conforming to that type must accept an inner `ClassParameterConstructor` that can construct any kind of `ClassParameter`, not just the specialized constructor for `MyClassParameter`. But then how do I solve this? In the interface I cannot be narrower than in the implementation and in the implementation I cannot just accept any kind of `ClassParameterConstructor`, the implementation `MyClassAsParameterNeeder` might specifically need Constructors for `MyClassParameter`...

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have tried to map the solution by @jcalz to my actual problem:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAehAIBcAsEsGdwPAQ3AYwPYDt0FMAHScAM0wCdVwB3clAgvSsyg6AT3lnUT2wHNY2PPFAR4mKNDzsMKbOABGecHgAe6aPP54AJktkArAK7xim7UP5UuAgDYq7QlZhIZMuvMDGo7d8Gyc3LwCzogAtqbEsOEEDuF8kABc3kKQTCQo+OAAylqMAJLY6eSZ+ADewODV4OEo8PBJ2MbhyuTAAL6pxRlZKgDCsOToDkUlZSrq6di6iHn0eGO9FVU1dLqwpk0tbZ3AacsqOQCOxijkiz2lfapq07O5+ZfjfZU14Fye261Me-tXE3AACVYIJdAAhDzsJbXfAAHhyt3ucyeMImAD43jV4E8kjk-mBangYB5wABBJJIWLxRJSZAHWF4FIMwEABQ4XB4aL6CKRfAe80KAL6mNW1UGwwclOE1HAAAoAJTgAC86PAEpGz0OYtyp3OTPAMvlStVurOF25+B1ILBkN07GleFlcpxC36dnqjUNTuNKrVORNaptsAhUMteAR6IJEASJP04MpphUMGQfEEwncsUw8CYUhQ0WwJCYiEg7EYjWADnMmCzOfZQR4AFFQsJ3Z6VaRjLhILAcHCdY2AHIAcQKg8bOQAEmTWY2+TMUQtwwAaAcjseN-oFIH9AAyc6m-MQGtGwvwq-eQ9H45yAEUAKpkoEHu5Hs36ldr68T6ezgDSY4ACLzg8V4blOM6NheNRgeOQLggA8oBACaIGIMGob2uGcKwT+kEAYOgFRuico6oKeBtg0jrUIqfrgLhEGztB4pDJqlFejKtGmrhW47vuzHvhc7HUb63HrjeD5PlB1qgiGdrQmeBqcfA6BNE6XFqgxv6NgRgGBvR4mNvBSHIcACpYtUFyQMY5AKCM7YWe86qsQ4HYnhRHoNDq7wnOaKjKoJHmet5NQYfJHZhWGik6l0XQ+DEcR4AkxT5r2CgsDYjDoLAJDcAEHLBKoLYqHK0gXAEABMCopMA9kNOArIVeRVKJclkCLkKLwrO8dT1QFACMOoEE1WU5dw5E5NZJBuAFAAss1-HViCNe5aENU1TwtTSxTHi5WqMo56ybIgA1DSNeDZbl6DuZNxjTR2FWDXFS3rb5+prY1zUJdt7WBeGjmfP54AVWdOSjVdb0XLd90DSDz2ectFWRfavKHgur1PGq31JYk6GyZhCldRGOSiu8rqMJS+LvMNYMXWN6DydDM3gAAzAA7DqWDYGY5DGOgkAUHK5HCd6NH6QGjnvCm8AAHTk0DRrCwjioxYtCPrfWnLwGSW04ztDUFVyilwp9mOOatAUrXtZF6uVltNbbXjvMjsj2y7oPg9wzbpngTMdv1LMs38VYa4b8Dgh2WC1ngmvBN7zjsaR7ymwsy7re5aefY7mdI-j8lmd4hKmCgOiFxAMAuNgdiyHENzUGVybSKg-NnH4si0PQjD6GmzhIIgKB+Jg1B6FAkjKESxRpXolbErU7CxzwOsBUajUL9rKs+HgABuTDsCmAiqHYOZ90VPsALRCJ4jAzIkM-EOE7DufJS+i3Pa9kjLLtyg-78y+5CrAAfk-KEH95YyyOqYDsQcy5QBED2A+FdSBZAFuQWAI8e7CDvm-MOEdl4+lXjgjeIcH6QzwPJXBr8f44M-nnKE3957UNIQAkhjtyFyyeHLEMQMACs3ggA)

Here I have actually already tried to use generics before but so far I put the <> behind the new (line 26):

```
RigidBody: new<S extends ShapeInterface> (shapeClass: new () => S) => RigidBodyInterface<S>
```

which didn't work. Now I have moved it up into the constructor of PhysicsInterface (line 23 where it is now) and it works.

However, now I have to list all the abstract classes that the engine uses in the generics parameter list, which is a bit ugly (especially since TypeScript doesn't display generics parameters as a tooltip) but I guess it makes sense.

I have also tried to build a type-inferring factory but in the end I didn't manage to make it work (the last line throws an error) and I think it's also too confusing and I would also need a way to inject engine-specific implementations for the physics engine class into the physics engine class factory so I think I will just go with method A.

However: The way it is now implemented, a user of the physics engine can access the p2-specific members of the classes and they are also listed in the TypeScript code completion. Is there a way to make that private but so that the engine itself can still access all p2 fields? Something I would use `friend` for in C++...

I have a working solution now but I still appreciate any helpful remarks on how I would make the factory work if I wanted to and about the whole concept in general.

Thanks!

Comment: the type of a constructor taking a constructor is written `type C = new (CPrime: new (x: SomeParam) => IPrime) => I`. No need for intermediate types to describe it

Comment: Thanks, that was my attempt to reduce the confusing nesting a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code for your `MyClassParameterNeeder` constructor says it needs a `MyClassParameter` *instance*, but it looks like your intent is for it to take a `MyClassParameter` *constructor*.  That is, `mcpc` should not be annotated as type `MyClassParameter`, but as `typeof MyClassParameter` or as `new () => MyClassParameter`:

```
class MyClassParameterNeeder implements ClassParameterNeeder {
   y = 19
   otherExtraField = 29
   constructor(mcpc: new () => MyClassParameter) { } // changed here
}
```

Once you fix that you still run into the issue where `MyClassParameterNeeder` is not a valid `ClassParameterNeederConstructor`, but now the error message is at least in line with the real problem that you've identified:

```
let doesntWork: ClassParameterNeederConstructor = MyClassParameterNeeder
//Type 'typeof MyClassParameterNeeder' is not assignable to type 'ClassParameterNeederConstructor'.
//Types of parameters 'mcpc' and 'cpc' are incompatible.
//Type 'new () => ClassParameter' is not assignable to type 'new () => MyClassParameter'.
//Property 'extraField' is missing in type 'ClassParameter' but required in type 'MyClassParameter'.
```

---

So, it sounds like your implementation of `MyClassParameterNeeder` is really what you want it to be: `mcpc` has to construct `MyClassParameter` instances specifically, not just any old `ClassParameter`.  That means your `ClassParameterNeederConstructor` is not the right type for you to be using.

Let's imagine you created a new `ClassParameter` subclass and an associated "needer" for it:

```
class AnotherClassParameter implements ClassParameter {
   x = 12
   foo = true
}

class AnotherClassParameterNeeder implements ClassParameterNeeder {
   y = 19
   bar = false
   constructor(mcpc: new () => AnotherClassParameter) { }
}
```

Note that you can't expect to use the same type to describe *both* `MyClassParameterNeeder` and `AnotherClassParameterNeeder`, without losing information you care about.  If you tried to represent those as a common type you'd need to either widen it to something type safe but useless:

```
type UselessClassParameterNeederConstuctor =
   new (cpc: new () => never) => ClassParameterNeeder

const uselessMine: UselessClassParameterNeederConstuctor = MyClassParameterNeeder;
const uselessAnother: UselessClassParameterNeederConstuctor = AnotherClassParameterNeeder;
new uselessMine(MyClassParameter); // error, can't call it
```

or use unsoundness somewhere to get something that you could use but would be dangerous:

```
type UnsoundClassParameterNeederConstuctor =
   new (cpc: new () => any) => ClassParameterNeeder

const unsoundMine: UnsoundClassParameterNeederConstuctor = MyClassParameterNeeder;
const unsoundAnother: UnsoundClassParameterNeederConstuctor = AnotherClassParameterNeeder;
new unsoundMine(AnotherClassParameter); // no error, but there should be
```

---

You need a type that can *change* depending on the which `ClassParameter` subclass constructor is needed.  This implies that `ClassParameterNeederConstructor` should be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
type ClassParameterNeederConstructor<C extends ClassParameter> =
   new (cpc: new () => C) => ClassParameterNeeder

const genericMine: ClassParameterNeederConstructor<MyClassParameter> =
  MyClassParameterNeeder;
const genericAnother: ClassParameterNeederConstructor<AnotherClassParameter> =
  AnotherClassParameterNeeder;

new genericMine(MyClassParameter); // okay, as desired
new genericAnother(AnotherClassParameter); // okay, as desired
new genericMine(AnotherClassParameter); // error, as desired
```

That works!

---

If you don't like having to manually specify the generic type parameter in your annotations, you can make a helper function to *infer* it for you:

```
const asClassParameterNeederConstructor =
   <C extends ClassParameter>(c: ClassParameterNeederConstructor<C>) => c;

const inferredMine = asClassParameterNeederConstructor(MyClassParameterNeeder);
const inferredAnother = asClassParameterNeederConstructor(AnotherClassParameterNeeder);
new inferredMine(MyClassParameter); // okay, as desired
new inferredAnother(AnotherClassParameter); // okay, as desired
new inferredMine(AnotherClassParameter); // error, as desired
```

You can see that `inferredMine` is inferred to be of type `ClassParameterNeederConstructor<MyClassParameter>` and `inferredAnother` is inferred to be of type `ClassParameterNeederConstructor<AnotherClassParameter>` automatically.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrAzgLgLACh8o4k1ZQBhAG2QwwAVl5kBbWY0Ab31B4A8tQkAK7MARgnwBffIRgIU6CtVoMmrYgDlYsACYJO3HgE8BwsRLzSC1kLbv2Hjp86cy8ICMwAOlWKxjI0OAA9pDYbqjKGKAAskZUNPSMLGz64N6+-tDRCSrJ6vpceDygvKAAvKAAjABMhqCwvNBMAGLgsJQ6FaA1AOxSEVGx8VGqKZraevCePn6wMDmj+anwWrqF9UbdVQCc9cHQABYIAKJNre2d3TV7xTyooRjNQqjQwfAAFMyoXqimsAB3UAfACUFQAfMNckk1CswRxQFYrG5oEYvGQAELIHTQsYFVaTBDkR7PV7vCr1SCA4E-P6CamgiFKRJ4uFM3HLCbreBuXzQUA6YKYGAAdXeAGsBFicUtYVypsSwqS3tNKnEOXKEGspvgPAAVNFkADkqPRwUQUNl4y1hPgRog0UgB1AiXAAHNIMhRL5QG9fYbQEbpRrrQTuYqnvAXiqjQA6XVgA3o6Lm0BeTkIaJG76-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-JGQLqNtHKeKeOydp0dKEG2jB+t2k78X2lLtPw8SQOelYQvwPLrs22APluojMvKyqwCdBp4Bq+rr35GKyAwQ5+qucQurweShuS3ixoAHnIBomnmHRFm+4hIR0ujhKm4SFvIem9ttFalVAN15gQcBUEBgRsY03H+LxkqqPxSnJ1Kl6zrC1n2apeAuZB3mmZxyN8ZBtSxfV5Wphy0dZc57miuFpapIqjxgnFZAjHqmgBUwJ9dD+6l9fl1AQeBgivoluEzbAC2rZt6I9APZ8naBF2ucBj3PtB8nTYh6HYZdIP7dDmzWZoPmiRJPjUqpkoCaJuACzJ72KY+Oks58gWVQJ8EFtQHLpcuqBEGq3RAe6TPtezmv3mK46y6SqZyub-lW-bm7PdVZOq5G3P+61uOsvgUfcupCeYY7o3B5Fn2E-963k7tkPHfXoFN+fd2l6H1ffdAQ-A5Ph2dDD48263jaipvvfiHBqqYbvCfsHF+bhQBAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves it! I've also fixed the question.